# Inside a chroot execvp() returns "Argument list too long"

Tags: linux, makefile, libc, chroot, execvp

I'm having an issue running a massive command inside a chroot. The command itself is triggered by a Makefile so the error is the classical:

```
make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

I did investigate and I understood looking at make's source code that it creates a job via execvp() which is provided by libc (I've seen the command is passed as "/bin/sh" "-c" "...my arguments").
So I looked the libc source and basically it looks there was a limit defined by ARG_MAX, however more recently it isn't used as the code says:

```
/* Legacy value of ARG_MAX.  The macro is now not defined since the
   actual value varies based on the stack size.  */
#define legacy_ARG_MAX 131072
```

So it thought I need to change the stack size via:

```
ulimit -s VALUE
```

So I compared the value outside the chroot and I did set a much larger value inside the chroot. However same result...
Do anyone have an idea? I don't know whether I'm investigating in the wrong direction or not.
Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Duplicate? - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument

Comment: I don't know whether it is, as this might be related to the fact that it fails inside the chroot and it have the feeling it might be related to it, as there are for sure limitations with it, but I don't know what...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having an issue running a massive command inside a chroot.
>
> Does anyone have an idea?

The command line typically shares the space with the environment variables and stack, and however hard you try to stretch them, there is still a limit.

The long-term solution is to avoid pushing against the limits. For example, instead of `sh -c "humongous command"`, from the make file write the `"humongous command"` into a temp file, and run `sh /tmp/filename` instead.

Comment: The problem is that in any way you want to interact with the shell through a command the Makefile has to expand the variable that holds the long command, so it will always fails. The option of constructing this long variable through string concatenation would not a viable option as it would imply to rewrite all the Makefiles, and it won't make sense as outside the chroot it builds fine.

Comment: @Stan, in that case I have no solution for you. You might have a better luck on ServerFault: this is not per se a software development topic, but rather the administration. Admins know better how to work with the system limits.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem replacing inside the Makefile very long relative paths to the objects files with a shorter version using a symbolic link to the base path for these object files.

```
@ln -s $(OBJ_BASE_PATH) ./a
NEW_OBJ_FILE_LIST=$(OLD_OBJ_FILE_LIST:$(OBJ_BASE_PATH)%=./a%)
```

After that the Makefile can expand $(NEW_OBJ_FILE_LIST) as it's shorter enough and it works.

I'm still puzzled though about the reason why outside the chroot it was working. I imagine the only reason would be that in some way...at some level...inside the chroot the system is 'concatenating' paths with the base path of the chroot like in my case "/var/chroots/my_long_path_to_the_chroot/" and so with that exceed the limit. I haven't any put any extra effort investigating that, so I do not confirm that, I'm just supposing.